# MVC Route conflicting with existing Folder causes 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I did see answers for similar issues, but none of them works for this situation.

I have MVC4 application with registered area called "Settings", with one "Manage"-controller. I also have folder in my web project with sources called "Settings", so the folder Structure is the following:

```
+ WebProjectFolder
     + Areas
          +Settings
               +Controllers
                    ManageController.cs
               + SettingsAreaRegistration.cs
               ...
     + Settings
          + SomeClasses.cs
```

ManageController is very simple:

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("WORKS FINE!");
    }
}
```

Area registration is also very simple:

```
public class SettingsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Settings";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Settings/{*pathinfo}");
        context.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

        context.MapRoute(
            "Settings_default",
            "Settings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {area = context.AreaName, controller="Manage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The problem:

```
http://mysite/settings - 404 
http://mysite/settings/Manage - 404
http://mysite/settings/Manage/Index - 404
```

In case I remove line "context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Settings/{*pathinfo}");"
Results are the following:

```
http://mysite/settings - 404
http://mysite/settings/Manage - WORKS FINE!
http://mysite/settings/Manage/Index - WORKS FINE!
```

Only If I remove/rename existing folder "Settings", then results are correct.
Similar situation with having controller named the same as folder.

How to make MVC ignore existing folder and always give priority to the Controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you wanted to set [RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) to `true`.

```
context.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Excerpt:

> true if ASP.NET routing handles all requests, even those that match an existing file; otherwise, false. The default value is false.

Comment: Setting RouteExistingFiles = true is the "nuclear option" for routing. It means we route all matching requests, whether or not the file exists. [See this question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1263849.aspx)